# spring boot with maven modules dependencies not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, module, pom.xml

Beating head in running a simple application in spring boot with one maven module dependency. This I try to run because I have to migrate a J2EE application to Springboot which has 7 modules... But I fail to run with one simple module.

Here is how I gave a try..

I downloaded a sample application and made it parent with pom packing..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>PesPdfExtractService</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.it.pes</groupId>
    <artifactId>pes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pes</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>PDF Extraction Service Application using Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and Created a maven dependency module as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>pes</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.it.pes</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>PesPdfExtractService</artifactId>

</project>
```

By default the Spring boot application class was on the parent module so I placed it in submodule

```
package com.it.pes.pdfextract.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.it.pes.pdfextract.controller")
    public class PesApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(PesApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Finally created a controller to test whether application is up or not.

```
package com.it.pes.pdfextract.controller;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test(){

        return "hello spring boot world";
    }
}
```

When I did mvn clean install, successfully it builds but the tom cat doesn't start at all and renders the below message

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64776:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/apatro/MyWorkspace/pes/PesPdfExtractService/target/classes:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.26/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.21.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.21.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.40/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-annotations-api/8.5.40/tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.40.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.40/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.40.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.40/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.40.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.6.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.11.3/jackson-databind-2.8.11.3.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.11/jackson-core-2.8.11.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar:/Users/apatro/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.24.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar com.it.pes.pdfextract.app.PesApplication
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.21.RELEASE)

Jul 18, 2019 12:07:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jul 18, 2019 12:07:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.40
Jul 18, 2019 12:07:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

I don't at all understand how to start with this .. could you please help me to move forward this. your help would be appreciated

Comment: honestly i did not understand the question, and also is there any error message?

Comment: No there is no error.. when I start  the application I found the message in console "INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext".. It didn't show me tomcat started in port so and so.... In general the application is not up I mean to say.

Comment: @Deadpool, thank you for your time .. I restarted my system and re build it. and removed the exclusions as well and I see it is working now... Thank you all whoever visited the question